# Image gallery not works when I click on youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube

In my website I have a images gallery, if you click on video thumbnail he shows perfectly but if you click on image thumbnail, this not works.

Check my gallery [here][1].

I have a function called muestraVideo(idyoutube).This function receives the parameter 'idyoutube':

```
function muestraVideo(idyoutube)
{
    $('#video_prod')[0].style.display = 'block';
    $('#gallery')[0].style.display = 'none';
    $('#iframe_video')[0].src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+idyoutube+'?autoplay=1&rel=0';
}
```

It's very simple, but console of Google Chrome not show errors.

What's the problem?

Many thanks.

[1]:

Comment: If you select the video and then select an image, the images is changing "hence no errors" but you can't see it because the gallery div container has the css property `display` set to `none`. You will need to add the following into the function that changes the images `$('#video_prod')[0].style.display = 'none'; $('#gallery')[0].style.display = 'block';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure when you click on image thumbnail you hide the iframe and show gallery div

i checked your code. Try adding following line inside thumb img click function:

```
$('#gallery_thumbs img').click(function(){
  $('#video_prod')[0].style.display = 'none';
    $('#gallery')[0].style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the video div is over the gallery images, when you open it. 
You have to hide the video div when you click again on an image